# How to calculate the derivative of following integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral

I did an exercise which would like to calculate the derivative in $x$ of the integral $$T(x) = \int\limits_0^{1} t^2 (1-t)^3 (t-x)^4 dt,$$
Of course, I showed that $$\dfrac{d}{dx} T(x) = - 4 \int\limits_0^{1} t^2 (1-t)^3 (t-x)^3 dt . $$

The problem is that I'd like a general resultat which can give a method to determinate the derivative in $x$ of the integral $T_1(x) = \int\limits^1_0 f(t, x) dt$ where $f(t,x) $ is a polynomial function of $t$ and $x$.

**My question:** Is there a resultat to determinate the derivative in $x$ of the integral $T_1(x) = \int\limits^1_0 f(t, x) dt$ where $f(t,x) $ is a polynomial function of $t$ and $x$?

Thank you very much for your interests!

Comment: Have you learned about partial derivatives?  You can do this by Leibniz's rule for [differentiation under the integral sign.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: Multiply out the polynomials.  You should get the same result regardless of whether you differentiate with respect to $x$ before or after you integrate.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, it is nice! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $a$ and $b$ are constants, and 
$$F(x)=\int_a^b f(x,t)dt$$ 
then 
$$F'(x)=\int_a^b\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)dt$$
for a sufficient function $f$. Here $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ denotes the [partial derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative). More details can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).